# Is there a built-in function in Matlab for calculating following integral?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I need to find the value of the following integral:

[image]

Does anybody know if there is a built-in function in Matlab for calculating this?

Comment: Do you want it solved analytically or numerically? Have you tried other alternatives, like wolframalpha?

Comment: i want to solve it numerically. Yes i have tried in WA but the problem is that i want to run the integral within a loop therefore it is better if i find some function in matlab

Comment: I'll chime in with "probably not".  It looks like an upper incomplete gamma with a weird exponential scaling/damping factor.  Unless someone else has seen this before, I'd suggest throwing it through `integral` as a possible path forward.

Comment: @TroyHaskin this function is discussed in Generalized incomplete gamma functions with applications by chaudhry et al. Its definition is provided in the paper in eq (5). Although the authors has written it the same way as the gamma notation but I do not know why the definition in wolfram site is different

Comment: @FrankMoses I searched around for a bit and I don't think MATLAB has an built-in function for evaluating that generalized representation of the incomplete gamma function. You might have to resort to using `integral`.

Comment: @edwinksl i tried using integral but i think due to infinity limit it is unable to give me any answer

Answer (score 2):

In reading through the [referenced paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042794901872), which was later expanded into [a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xfTKBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=On+a+Class+of+Incomplete+Gamma+Functions+with+Applications&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj13fuFjOzNAhWG9R4KHWt8BEcQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=On%20a%20Class%20of%20Incomplete%20Gamma%20Functions%20with%20Applications&f=false), I don't see any direct equality expressed for the author's definition of the generalized incomplete gamma function that can be replicated using the Matlab's [Elementary Math](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/elementary-math.html) library.  The authors actually use the IMSL Fortran subroutine QDAGI to directly integrate and generate their table of values (sadly, only given to five decimal places).  Therefore, the most direct route in evaluating such a function is to use `integral`.

The raw incomplete generalized gamma function can be written inline as

```
iggamma = @(x,alpha,b) integral(@(t) (t+x).^(alpha-1) .* exp(-(t+x)-b./(t+x)),0,Inf,'ArrayValued',true)
```

where I shifted `t` to `t+x` such that the lower bound was always `0` and an array-valued `x` could be passed.  The table in the book scales this raw function by a term involving what the authors call a modified Bessel function of the third kind but what the Mathworks calls a modified Bessel function of the second kind `besselk` (because that's not confusing at all).  The scaled version would be:

```
iggammas = @(x,alpha,b) iggamma(x,alpha,b) ./ ( 2*b.^(alpha/2) .* besselk(alpha,2*sqrt(b)))
```

The scaled version matches most of the values I checked to four decimal places with a few disagreeing on the fifth; however, I would chalk this up to differences in rounding and integration tolerance parameters.